# How to count sum of occurrences of my list of words in dataframe row?

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x, string, dataframe

I want to count the occurrences of words of my list in a given dataframe column for each line.

Code:

```
 d2 = {}
 for key, lst in dict_.items():
    col_names = [element for element in lst if isinstance(element, str)]
    regex_lists = [element for element in lst if isinstance(element, list)]
    regex_list = functools.reduce(lambda x, y: x+y, regex_lists)
    map_function = lambda s: len(re.findall(r'|'.join(regex_list).lower(),  str(s).lower()))
   df_regex_count = df[col_names].applymap(map_function)
   df[key] = [sum(lst_tmp) for lst_tmp in    df_regex_count.values.tolist()]
```

My dataframe is:

```
 d = {'Column_1': ['mango juice pret Orange No manner  Emman snow', ' préts No  scan eblanc'],}
 df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
```

My list of words

```
list_1 = ['mango juice', 'Mango' ,'Orange', 'pr[éeêè]t[s]?']
dict = {"s1": ['Column_1', list_1]}
```

The output of s1 is [3,1] but it must me [4,1]. Because 'mango juice',mango,Orange,pret

[dictionary](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NufoW.png)

Creation of lists for csv file.

```
df['Word'] = r'\b' + df[' Word'].astype(str) + r'\b'
df.groupby('Country').agg(",".join).reset_index()
group1 =df[df['Country']== 1]
list1.append("|".join(group1['Word']))
```

[image: ListWithout('|').]

Comment: can you provide sample data and expected output?

Comment: @QuangHoang Yes i edited my original post. My code works perfectly but doesn't treat the case of 'mango juice', 'Mango'. Thank you

Comment: @QuangHoang do you see what i mean?

Comment: I tried your code and got [5, 1]. I guess because "mango" is counted trice. Once matching "mango juice" twice matching "mango" (the "mango" in "mango juice" is counted again).

Comment: @Valentino I edited my code . Have a look please thank you

Comment: yes, now is [3, 1], I did not notice the mango inside Emmango

Comment: yep @Valentino but it must me [4,1] according to mango juice and mango.

Comment: Ah, right. From the docs of [re.findall](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/re.html): "Return all non-overlapping matches of pattern in string". So once 'mango juice' is found, it does not find again the mango inside it. It's how re.findall works

Comment: Ok thank you. Is there solution ? @valentino

Comment: The solution would be to not combine the words to search with `|` in the regex, but to search them one by one with a loop over `regex_list`, count them separately and sum the results.

Comment: I didnt understand @valentino

Answer (score 0):

[re.findall](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/re.html) returns all non-overlapping matches of a pattern in a string.
It means that the string is consumed while searching for a match in the pattern. So if a substring of a match is a match itself, is missed.

This is what happens with `'mango'` and `'mango juice'` in your case, since your regex combines all the strings to be matched with an `or`.

If you want to look for overlapping cases, do not combine the words to search with `|` in the regex but perform a search for each word.

```
def map_function(s, reglst):
    matches = [len(re.findall(rg.lower(), s.lower())) for rg in reglst]
    return sum(matches)
```

Here I redefine your `map_function`. It uses a list comprehension to perform `re.findall` once for each single word of `regex_list` and returns the sum of all occurrences.

Then your code would be:

```
for key, lst in dict_.items():
    col_names = [element for element in lst if isinstance(element, str)]
    regex_lists = [element for element in lst if isinstance(element, list)]
    regex_list = functools.reduce(lambda x, y: x+y, regex_lists)
    df_regex_count = df[col_names].applymap(lambda s : map_function(s, regex_list))
    df[key] = [sum(lst_tmp) for lst_tmp in df_regex_count.values.tolist()]
```

Now `df` s:

```
                                        Column_1  s1
0  mango juice pret Orange No manner  Emman snow   4
1                          préts No  scan eblanc   1
```

#### EDIT

You need your regex list `list1` to be something of the like:

```
list1 = [r'\bmango juice\b', r'\bMango\b' ,r'\bOrange\b', r'\bpr[éeêè]t[s]?\b']
```

So a list which one word per element. Looking at your code, you probably can create it in this way:

```
df['Word'] = r'\b' + df[' Word'].astype(str) + r'\b'
df.groupby('Country').agg(",".join).reset_index()
group1 =df[df['Country']== 1]
list1.extend(group1['Word'])
```

Comment: thank you but it doesn't work for me since i want to read these keywords from a csv file. I edited my post to add figure showing my dictionary

Comment: I do not see why it should not work. All I did was to change the function passed to apply. It does not matter from where you read the keywords.

Comment: i don't really know whats the matter. notice that im creating lists of key words when reading a csv file. df = pd.read_csv(File,sep=';',encoding='latin-1'). I have edited my original post to show how to create my lists.

Comment: Could you show the real `list1`? It seems you are building the regex with the `|` when you are reading the data, and not in the `map_function` as you did in the original question

Comment: Can't you simply build the list without `|`? If you want to search for overlapping matches, you must avoid it. You simply need a list of words, and then my solution will work.

Comment: i tried but it gives count = 0.. I added capture of my list know